# Create accessible PDF Files with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

im trying to create a barrier-free pdf-document with Ghostscript (Version 9.54)
In the end i need a pdf file which contains tags in it.

I was trying to use the following command, but it didn't work.

**gsprint.exe -ghostscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\GS\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -dPDFA=2 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 -dNOOUTERSAVE -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB -sOutputFile=""C:\temp\ghost\pdfua.pdf"" ""C:\temp\test23.pdf""**

Ghostscript creates a new pdf in the specified folder (c:\temp\ghost\pdfua.pdf) but there are no tags in it.

Have you guys some ideas?

thx

Comment: What is a 'barrier-free PDF' ? That is not a term I've ever heard. What do you mean by 'tags ? Marked content ? Structure information ? Ghostscript's PDF interpreter currently does not preserve either of those. It looks to me like you are trying to create an 'accessible' PDF file going by the filename 'pdfua.pdf'. You can create marked content in the output by using pdfmarks, which you will have to construct manually yourself. Logical structure pdfmarks aren't supported at all. Is the original input file an accessible PDF file ?

Comment: Yes, i meant an accessible PDF File. 
When you open the acrobat reader, under "FILE", Properties... the item "PDF with tags" must be listed with "yes"
Do you know, if Ghostscript supports that feature?

Comment: Ghostscript's pdfwrite cannot manufacture an accessible PDF file from one which is not already accessible. How would it know (for example) the reading order or the language ? The pdfwrite device supports various pdfmarks (such as marked content) which form part of the 'tagged PDF' format, but Ghostscript's PDF interpreter does not pass on marked content to the output device. In addition neither the interpreter nor the pdfwrite device support structure info. So in short, no you cannot create an accessible PDF file with Ghostscript's pdfwrite device.